# unique_ptr constructor with rvalue deleter returns null?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Here's a code snippet I'm using to understand the behavior of `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::default_delete<int> d;
std::unique_ptr<int> u1;
std::unique_ptr<int> u2 (nullptr);
std::unique_ptr<int> u3 (new int);
std::unique_ptr<int> u4 (new int, d);
std::unique_ptr<int> u5 (new int, std::default_delete<int>());
std::unique_ptr<int> u6 (std::move(u5));
std::unique_ptr<int> u7 (std::move(u6));
std::unique_ptr<int> u8 (std::auto_ptr<int>(new int));

std::cout << "u1: " << (u1?"not null":"null") << '\n';
std::cout << "u2: " << (u2?"not null":"null") << '\n';
std::cout << "u3: " << (u3?"not null":"null") << '\n';
std::cout << "u4: " << (u4?"not null":"null") << '\n';
std::cout << "u5: " << (u5?"not null":"null") << '\n';
std::cout << "u6: " << (u6?"not null":"null") << '\n';
std::cout << "u7: " << (u7?"not null":"null") << '\n';
std::cout << "u8: " << (u8?"not null":"null") << '\n';
```

Can somebody explain why `null` is printed for `u5` and `u6`, but not for `u7`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` always has a single owner. When you move the ownership, the original pointer become null. So if you insert printing statements between some declaration, it would become obvious when value become null. Using a debugger is another way to help understand code **as it would be reading the documentation**.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation, I was scratching my head wondering why, now I see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Phil1970 pointed out in his comment a `std::unique_pointer` instance becomes (equivalent to) `nullptr` after it is assigned to another instance (using `std::move` as seen in your code example). Actually this is what `std::unique_ptr` is made for. It is, well, unique.

Now consider this piece of code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::default_delete<int> d;
    std::unique_ptr<int> u1;
    std::cout << "u1: " << (u1 ? "not null" : "null") << '\n';

    std::unique_ptr<int> u2(nullptr);
    std::cout << "u2: " << (u2 ? "not null" : "null") << '\n';

    std::unique_ptr<int> u3(new int);
    std::cout << "u3: " << (u3 ? "not null" : "null") << '\n';

    std::unique_ptr<int> u4(new int, d);
    std::cout << "u4: " << (u4 ? "not null" : "null") << '\n';

    std::unique_ptr<int> u5(new int, std::default_delete<int>());
    std::cout << "u5: " << (u5 ? "not null" : "null") << '\n';

    std::unique_ptr<int> u6(std::move(u5));
    std::cout << "u6: " << (u6 ? "not null" : "null") << '\n';

    std::unique_ptr<int> u7(std::move(u6));
    std::cout << "u7: " << (u7 ? "not null" : "null") << '\n';
}
```

When [executed](https://ideone.com/yCjXxK) you see that `u5` and `u6` are "not null" immediately after instantiation.